# How to get acces to inputValue of Autocomplete from meterial UI using a reference (React.useRef)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am trying to get access to the current value that is in inputValue of Autocomplete. indeed, I am passing a reference to the Autocomplete (functional component) but can't figure out how to get access to the current value of inputValue to check if the value is still the same to perform some logic.

```
... other codes 

 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
 const autoRef = useRef();
 useEffect(() => {
 console.log(autoRef.current); // gives MU div and div ...
 const timer = setTimeout(() => {
 if(inputValue === ???){
     // user did not change inputValue since then 
 }
 }, 200);
 return () => {
   clearTimeout(timer);
 };
 }, [inputValue]);

  <Autocomplete
    ref={autoRef}
    inputValue={inputValue}
    onInputChange={(event, value) => setInputValue(value)}
   renderInput... 
   />

... other codes
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states you should be controlling the state of value and inputValue separately

Comment: the question is not about controlling the inputValue, but how to access that via a ref, on simple input it is refVariable.current.value. but this can not be done on Autocomplete.  @aznbanana9

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoRef.current.value, this is the reference for your input.